# Seaborn pairplot with different data on each triangle

Tags: python, seaborn

I wanted to do a pairplot with two different dataframes `data_up` and `data_low` on the lower part and the upper part of the pairgrid. The two dataframes have both 4 columns, wich correspond to the variables.

Looking at Pairgrid, i did not found a way to give different data to each triangle.

e.g :

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# Dummy data : 
data_up = np.random.uniform(size=(100,4))
data_low = np.random.uniform(size=(100,4))

# The two pairplots i currently uses and want to mix :
sns.pairplot(pd.DataFrame(data_up))
sns.pairplot(pd.DataFrame(data_low))
```

How can i have only the upper triangle of the first one plotted witht he lower traingle of the second one ? On the diagonal i dont really care what's plotted. Maybe a qqplot between the two corresponding marginals could be nice, but i'll see later.

Comment: I switched language and therefore never found a python solution, but I do not care anymore. Maybe for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put all columns together in the dataframe, and then use `x_vars=...` to tell which columns to use for the x-direction. Similar for y.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# Dummy data :
data_up_down = np.random.uniform(size=(100,8))
df = pd.DataFrame(data_up_down)

# use columns 0..3 for the x and 4..7 for the y
sns.pairplot(df, x_vars=(0,1,2,3), y_vars=(4,5,6,7))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```